# Possible ways to feed two variables containing text data into an ML model in an NLP problem

Tags: classification, natural-language, similarities

In a **natural language processing (NLP)** problem, we have a couple of variables, say A and B. A denotes a phrase (1-2 words) and B denotes another phrase (>3 words). There is one target variable that demonstrates the **similarity score between A and B** for each instance. The similarity scores are characterized in one of these ordered categories; [0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0]. The description of these scores are as follows;

1.0 - Very close match. This is typically an exact match except possibly for differences in conjugation, quantity (e.g. singular vs. plural), and addition or removal of stopwords (e.g. “the”, “and”, “or”).

0.75 - Close synonym, e.g. “mobile phone” vs. “cellphone”. This also includes abbreviations, e.g. "TCP" -> "transmission control protocol".

0.5 - Synonyms which don’t have the same meaning (same function, same properties). This includes broad-narrow (hyponym) and narrow-broad (hypernym) matches.

0.25 - Somewhat related, e.g. the two phrases are in the same high level domain but are not synonyms. This also includes antonyms.

0.0 - Unrelated.

So, I'm treating it as a classification problem. I wish to know two things;

1. Whether it is imperative to treat it as a classification problem?
2. How do I use A and B as features? Must I convert them into bag of words? If yes, how? What are the possible ways that I could employ?

Comment: [0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0] is not a range. Do you mean that there are only 5 distinct values of the target value? Are these values truly numerical? Or do they encode something like "not similar", "somewhat dissimilar", "neither similar nor dissimilar", "somewhat similar", "very similar"? If so, an **ordered** scale seems more appropriate, e.g. [tag:ordered-logit].

Comment: @Sycorax , yes, it is not a range and it is as you say ("not similar", "somewhat similar", etc.). It is ordered. The description of the target variable goes; "the similarity. This is sourced from a combination of one or more manual expert ratings".

Comment: Ok, so to answer (1) suggests you don't want a classification model, but instead an ordered logit or similar model that reflects the fact that the target is an ordered value.

Comment: @Sycorax Could ordered logit be used with BERT or Transformers for that matter?

Comment: Ordered logit is just a loss function. BERT and Transformers are just ways of creating representations from inputs. As long as the output of the model is consistent with the loss you've implemented, it will work.

Comment: Could you please comment on the second question?

Comment: Use any NLP method. There's not much basis from the question to distinguish between alternative choices.